# React Child componentDidMount not triggering on Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am very new to React and have been looking into building my first react app with a headless WP backend.

I am having trouble getting `componentDidMount` to trigger in my `MoviePage` class. I was hoping someone could help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code, it is probably not perfect as this is my first try.

**NOTE CODE HAS NOW CHANGED TO ADD SUGGESTIONS FROM COMMENTS - check edit history for original code (it's still broken)**

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render((
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    ), 
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Header from './components/Header';
import Main from './components/Main';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Main />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let dataURL = "http://localhost:8888/SBP/website/wp-json/wp/v2/movies?_embed";

    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          movies: response
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    let movieLinks = this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => {
      return <li key={index}><Link to={'/movies/'+movie.id}>{movie.title.rendered}</Link></li>
    });

    return (
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to='/movies'>All Movies</Link></li>
            {movieLinks}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    )
  }  
}

export default Header;
```

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Movies from './Movies';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Route path='/movies' component={Movies}/>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Movies.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, } from "react-router-dom";

import MoviesHub from './MoviesHub';
import MoviePage from './MoviePage';

class Movies extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/movies' component={MoviesHub}/>
        <Route path='/movies/:number' component={MoviePage}/>
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

export default Movies;
```

MoviesHub.js

```
import React from 'react';

class MoviesHub extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let dataURL = "http://localhost:8888/SBP/website/wp-json/wp/v2/movies?_embed";
    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          movies: res
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    let movies = this.state.movies.map((movie, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>
      <img src={movie._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.large.source_url} alt={movie.title.rendered} />
      <p><strong>Title:</strong> {movie.title.rendered}</p>
      <p><strong>Release Year:</strong> {movie.acf.release_year}</p>
      <p><strong>Rating:</strong> {movie.acf.rating}</p>
      <div><strong>Description:</strong><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: movie.acf.description} } /></div>
      </div>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Star Wars Movies</h2>
        {movies}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MoviesHub;
```

MoviePage.js

```
import React from 'react';

class MoviePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movie: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('MoviePage componentDidMount');

    let dataURL = 'http://localhost:8888/SBP/website/wp-json/wp/v2/movies/'+this.props.match.params.number;

    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        debugger;

        this.setState({
          movie: data
        })

        console.log("movie", this.state.movie);
      })
  }

  render() {
    let movie = this.state.movie;

    return <div>
        <img src={movie._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.large.source_url} alt={movie.title.rendered} />
        <p><strong>Title:</strong> {movie.title.rendered}</p>
        <p><strong>Release Year:</strong> {movie.acf.release_year}</p>
        <p><strong>Rating:</strong> {movie.acf.rating}</p>
        <div><strong>Description:</strong><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: movie.acf.description} } /></div>
      </div>
  }
}

export default MoviePage;
```

For reference I am building from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jchiatt/headless-wordpress-with-react-d573bca02ee0) and trying to take it to the next level

Any help will be greatly appreciated and also any advice on how to improve my code to keep in line with best practices would be great.

Thanks all.

Comment: have you tried to console.log("in componentDidMount") in componentDidMount method.

Comment: i would start by putting each component to it's own file so you can easily tell what's working and what's not and it's best practice as well.

Comment: @javed I have tried this, the `console.log` doesn't trigger, I get nothing in my console.

@iceveda06 This is what I was planning on doing next, but I am not sure the best way to layout the file structre yet

Comment: i checked that you had console log inside fetch. can you move it to first line of componentDidMount. if confirm it. because componentDidMount call once your component mounted . may be issue with your fetch call. check in network section.

Comment: so what i would do is, and this will help you troubleshoot and practice as well, put each 'class' in it's own component.  You also need to use ReactDOM to render your code to your browser.  I did not see that in your code unless it was inside index.js or something and App.js is rendered inside.

Comment: @javed I just tried your suggestion and the `console.log` does not trigger. Not when I land on my 'homepage' and not when I land on the matching URL. Very strange.

Comment: @iceveda06 You are right my `ReachDOM.render` is inside index.js, I have added that into my question now. I will try separating the classes into individual files to see if this will help me debug the issue.

Comment: this might be not an issue but try to modify return statement to return ( your  code ) in MoviePage.

Comment: Just checking the basics - are there any errors in the console? if you see any errors from the render step, you won't get to componentDidMount.

Comment: @javed Sorry I am not sure I understand what you want me to try?

Comment: I got fetch error but i would expect that since i can't point to proper API.  Check console as suggested by @AdamBerman if you see *Uncaught in promise then something is wrong with your promise part of the code

Comment: added more to my answer below

Comment: @AdamBerman and @iceveda06 I am getting the following console errors, but i don't think they help as they are just because `componentDidMount` is not running. 1st error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined - MoviePage.js` 2nd error `The above error occurred in the <MoviePage> component: - index.js` 3rd error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined - MoviePage.js`

Comment: Exactly - if you get those errors, the app will crash before componentDidMount has the chance to run. Clean up the errors, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @AdamBerman problem is I am using `componentDidMount` to get the data to fix the error, so how do I fix it? :/

Comment: I added an example below of how you can avoid calling anything on the movie object while you're waiting for it to load.

Comment: Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not actually attaching your react app to the DOM anywhere. Somewhere, you need to use ReactDOM to attach your app to some root element on the page. Then, your components will mount and render.

That might look something like this for you:

```
ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('my-root-element'))
```

Take a look at [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) for more info.

---

**Edit**

I think you're likely getting an error on render that is causing this. If you get an error on the initial render, you'll never make it to componentDidMount.

If you look at your `MoviePage` class, you set a state of `movie: []` on initialization. You'll eventually fetch a movie, which presumably will be an object. But before you've finished fetching your data, you'll call your render function, which is trying to access data on that movie, like:

```
movie._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.large.source_url
```

Two quick tips:

1. Pre-fill your state with something that is the same type as what you expect your state to return as. So if you expect movie to be an object, have the initial state be `movie: {}`.
2. Before you render elements using data, make sure the data is loaded. Have a condition where you render a spinner or a loading message until the data comes back.

Example render function:

```
render() {
  if (Object.keys(movie).length === 0) { // check if movie object is empty
    return <div>Data not loaded</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      ... whatever you had
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I just realised I am missing some of my code, very sorry, please check for updated question.

Comment: I tried changing `movie: []` to `movie: {}` which is correct but this did not help. I would like to add a spinner but I have no idea how to do this in React yet.

Comment: I added an example of how you can avoid calling anything on the movie object while you're waiting for it to load.

Comment: awesome! glad to help

Comment: Thanks again! Now I just need to figure out how to trigger it again when I navigate from `/movies/12` to `/movies/13` but thats a whole other issue

Comment: You're probably going to want to add a check in componentWillReceiveProps (assuming the url get's passed in as a prop by your router) to see if the id changed. Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html to get a better idea of how react lifecycle methods work.